# how do i return unique objectID when i prepareForSegue on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, parse-platform

i am using parse as the backend, i tried to output the below with NSlog, but i keep getting the same object id, please help

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier  isEqualToString:@"MoreDetails"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        MoreDetailsViewController *destVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *objectId = [object objectId];

        Offers *offers = [[Offers alloc]init];
        offers.offerID = objectId;

        destVC.offer = offers;
        NSLog(@"table view %@", objectId);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the index path in a log statement. It's probably not right.

Comment: keeps showing "indexpath 0" when i log it with  NSLog(@"indexpath %ld", (long)indexPath);

Comment: and same when i nslog  NSLog(@"indexpath %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

Comment: Is the segue linked from a cell in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With segues linked from storyboard cells, the cell may not be selected at the point the segue is prepared for.

Luckily, you have access to the cell itself because it is the `sender` of the segue.

Change this line of code:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

To

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
```

This will give you the correct index path.